# Determining which request can be granted as edge of hold,wait and illegal

Tags: graph, resources, operating-system, deadlock, cycle

Consider the resource allocation graph :-

[image]

Assume the sequence of requests is given as:
P4 → R3
P1 → R4
P3 → R1
P2 → R3
P4 → R2
P5 → R4

Which requests can be granted such that there should be no deadlock?

I tried solving it but just need a heads-up as I got confused browsing different graphs with different results.

This is my answer -
P4 → R3  - hold
P1 → R4  - wait
P3 → R1  - wait
P2 → R3  - wait
P4 → R2  - illegal
P5 → R4  - wait

Comment: @shekharsuman I did all the work in the book. It's a three-page long!

Comment: @shekharsuman- Here, a process can request any number of resources. And here illegal request is a request which when granted, the system goes in a deadlock state We don't need to use any algorithm here.

Comment: @shekharsuman have a look at this video - https://goo.gl/wWTLg4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I derived is the same as what you mentioned,CONGRATS for solving it on your own. I am just briefing it out for future visitors :-

```
P4 -> R3 ------ will hold as one instance of R3 is available.
P1 -> R4 ------ will wait as the only instance of R4 is occupied by P4.
P3 -> R1 ------ will wait as the only instance of R1 is occupied by P1.
P2 -> R3 ------ will wait as both instances of R3 are occupied by P3 and P4.
P4 -> R2 ------ will be illegal due to satisfying circular wait condition.
```

> ***Explanation of above*** **--->** P4 needs R2, which is occupied by P2 and P5. P2 needs R3 which is
>   occupied by P4 itself. So, here's a cycle which is an unsafe state.
>   Hence, this will result in deadlock due to circular wait.

```
P5 -> R4 ------ will wait in queue after P1, as P1 has requested for R4
                before than P5.
```

**NOTE :-** We won't consider the 5<sup>th</sup> case as it will result in deadlock and hence will not be considered in evaluation of the future requests of resources by the processes.